# Can't access some object data post ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback

In the code below, why does console.log(myObject.obj1 ) display a **proto** object in the console instead of actual object data? Meanwhile, I can see the obj1 data using console.log(myObject).

```
$(function () {

    var myObject = {
        obj1: {},
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "foobar.json",
        success: function (data) {
            myObject.obj1 = data.obj1;
        }
   });

    console.log(myObject); // displays myObject data in console!
    console.log(myObject.obj1 ) // displays a __proto__ object :(

});
```

**If this is related to async code, why does console.log(myObject) work? Maybe this is related to scope, i.e. myObject.obj1 being out of scope?**

Comment: Exactly, success handler will be called after the request is fulfilled. question: what do you get when you ```console.log(data)``` inside the success handler? like so: ```success: function (data) { console.log(data); };```

Comment: Can you post the exact console.log() statements output?

Comment: `If this is related to async code`,   There is no if here, it's async code.  `myObject.obj1 being out of scope?`  No, it's in scope, it's an async problem.

Comment: console.log(data) outputs full data from the json file as several objects.

Comment: However, if i print console.log(myObject.obj1 ) i get: {}
__proto__
:
constructor
:
ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
:
ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
:
ƒ toLocaleString()
toString
:
ƒ toString()
valueOf
:
ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__
:
ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
:
ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
:
ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
:
ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__
:
ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__
:
ƒ __proto__()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: It will work when you view it in console, as the console has captured the scope of myObject, so when the aJax call is finished you will see the result.  It's just the result updates that fast you don't see it's been done async.  By the time you click that plus to expand in the console window, you Ajax call has likely finished.

Comment: i still dont see the solution to my problem in those links because i cant access myObject.obj1 in the rest of the code.